# PyProj package installation PROJ_DIR variable

Tags: python, pip, package, proj, pyproj

I am attempting to install `pyproj`, although am getting a `Proj executable not found. Please set PROJ_DIR variable` error.

### COMMAND

`$ pipenv install pyproj`

I have also tried `pipenv git+https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj.git#egg=pyproj` for the same result.

### OUTPUT

`$ pipenv install pyproj
Installation Succeeded
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies
Locking ['packages] dependancies
Success!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock`

### ERROR

`[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['Collecting pyproj==2.0.0 (from -r /var/folders/g3/912
vtylj2hb71xf_d_8sxz480000gn/T/pipenv-qeun2uwi-requirements/pipenv-behbdii2-requirement.tx
t (line 1))', '  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/53/4b/21643a93e7d33
941498087290636e34c6d534aa8baa1ada54cf0d096ffaa/pyproj-2.0.0.tar.gz', '  Installing build
 dependencies: started', "  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'",
'  Getting requirements to build wheel: started', "  Getting requirements to build wheel:
 finished with status 'error'", '  Complete output from command /Users/darcyprice/.local/
share/virtualenvs/pure-dawn-52933-x98m1awW/bin/python3 /Users/darcyprice/.local/share/vir
tualenvs/pure-dawn-52933-x98m1awW/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_proc
ess.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /var/folders/g3/912vtylj2hb71xf_d_8sxz480000gn/T/tmpw
q5vvpkd:', '  Proj executable not found. Please set PROJ_DIR variable.', '  ', '  -------
---------------------------------']
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['Command "/Users/darcyprice/.local/share/virtualenvs/p
ure-dawn-52933-x98m1awW/bin/python3 /Users/darcyprice/.local/share/virtualenvs/pure-dawn-
52933-x98m1awW/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires
_for_build_wheel /var/folders/g3/912vtylj2hb71xf_d_8sxz480000gn/T/tmpwq5vvpkd" failed wit
h error code 1 in /private/var/folders/g3/912vtylj2hb71xf_d_8sxz480000gn/T/pip-install-t_
ap8o3w/pyproj']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Installation instructions](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/v2.2.0rel/installation.html) recommend to install precompiled wheels or use conda package manager.

In case you still want to compile PyProj from sources you need to [setup PROJ.4](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/v2.2.0rel/installation.html#setup-proj) (please understand that PyProj is a Python wrapper for Proj).

Comment: links are broken(

Comment: Thanks, fixed. The docs moved to https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/html/

Answer (score 9):

```
pip install pyproj==1.9.6
```

Same issues, used above.
Installs the latest version previous to March 8th, 2019, if that suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks, @Cloudwolfe for the answer! I installed proj version as suggested, but am still getting the same error. Can I ask, what version of `celery` you're running?