Does downloading Rust/Cargo impact python package installs?
I downloaded and set up Rust and Cargo two days ago. I know this is working correctly since I managed to write and run some very basic programs in the two on the terminal. Today I tried to download geopandas (pip install geopandas) on VScode and keep running into the following errors:
Collecting geopandas
  Using cached geopandas-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (323 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.22 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from geopandas) (1.24.2)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from geopandas) (23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=1.4.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from geopandas) (2.2.1)
Collecting pyproj>=3.3.0
  Using cached pyproj-3.7.0.tar.gz (225 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      proj executable not found. Please set the PROJ_DIR variable. For more information see: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/installation.html
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 24.3.1
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip

I tried upgrading pip and upgrading setuptools but nothing seems to be working. I've never seen this issue until I downloaded Rust so I'm wondering if it has something to do with that. Would appreciate any help!
Edit: Tried to upgrade pip and setuptools but still got the error seen above.
Same thing when I uninstalled Rust + Cargo and installed pyproj. Can't figure out what's the issue

See if anything here helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55084003/pyproj-package-installation-proj-dir-variable or here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64788000/installation-pyproj-does-not-work-returned-127

Why would this have anything to do with Rust? Proj is written in C++ and Pyproj is written in Python and Cython, none of them in Rust. Plus as you pointed out yourself, the issue persists when you uninstall Rust.

Have you tried installing another version of pyproj ? pip install pyproj==3.2.0 for example

thanks for all your help, everyone! It was an issue with the geopandas dependencies - I didn't have gdal installed, which was my bad. The new version of pyproj worked too, thanks @Lenormju
